# PHP and MySQL query doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I want to save the name of a picture in the database which is called "ergasia".I have created the table information with the columns name-surname-address-title_photo and i want to insert with a mysql query in this column the name of the picture.The picture is saved in a folder on desktop.Here is my query:

```
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root' ,'ana');
    $con=mysql_select_db('ergasia');
    $surname=$_SESSION['surname'];
    $name=$_SESSION['name'];
    $query= "UPDATE information SET title_photo='$_FILES["file"]["name"]' WHERE name='$name' AND lastname='$surname' ";
        if (!mysql_query($query)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

I get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier
>   (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in
>   C:\Users\anastasia\Desktop\xampp2\htdocs\ana\forma\save_file.php on
>   line 20

Do you have any idea about the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've got a problem with your quotes.  Look at the color syntax highlighting in your question to see it.

Comment: Assign `$_FILES["file"]["name"]` to a variable and use that in the query, otherwise you're going to have to deal with multiple quote types and escaping or concatenating them. Better yet, just switch to PDO since mysql_* is kaput.

Comment: hopefully someone doesn't upload a file called `'; drop table information #`

Comment: Also try to use mysqli_* functions. Usage of mysql_* functions is not recommeded.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is with the string query.Change it as follows.

```
$query= "UPDATE information SET title_photo='".$_FILES["file"]["name"]."' WHERE name='".$name."' AND lastname='".$surname ."'";
```

Comment: @user2820512 it works now, but its vulnerable to sql injection and this will fail when name contains a quote

Comment: @user2820512 yes, that's correct.But I think at begining it's enough.

Answer (score 4):

You have quoting issue, the proper way to do it in mysql is:

```
$query=  sprintf("UPDATE information SET title_photo='%s' 
                  WHERE name='%s' AND lastname='%s'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['file']['name']),
            mysql_real_escape_string($name)));
            mysql_real_escape_string($surname)));
```

... but it is a deprecated API, so please upgrade to mysqli if you can.

Comment: In this case the name and lastname are session variables which aren't likely to be tampered with. But definitely sanitize them regardless.

Answer (score 0):

change your query line with this:

```
$query= "UPDATE information SET title_photo='".$_FILES["file"]["name"]."' WHERE name='$name' AND lastname='$surname' ";
                                             ^^                       ^^
```

You have to correctly concatenate `$_FILES["file"]["name"]` with your query string.

Mysql extension is [officially deprecated as of PHP v5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php). Use [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that PHP sees that you try to end the string after the " (`$_FILES["file`). You have to [concatenate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation) (end the string, add the string value of a variable, then continue the string) the different values. Above answers will all work, so pick one and invest some time in understanding concatenation. Especially when you will often work with strings (like SQL queries) you will probably use this way more than once.